# How to transfer excel files to MacBook Air

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a new MacBook Air computer and would like to transfer my Excel spreadsheets from my Windows 7 to it.  How can I do this transfer without using a disk?

Comment: https://www.apple.com/ca/support/macbasics/migration/

Answer (score 0):

You could 1)install iCloud on the Windows machine and copy them to the iCloud folder, or 2)do the same thing with another cloud program such as Google drive or Microsoft OneDrive.

Comment: No problem. Cleaning up my comments ;)